# Why did Dr Strange mention traffic signal here?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, dr-strange-multiverse-of-madness

In *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness* (2022), America Chavez and Doctor Strange landed on Earth-838 by traveling through
the multiverse. On their way to find the other Doctor Strange, they met
838 Mordo:

> 838 MORDO: Come in, and tell me everything about your universe.
>
> Dr Strange: **You go on red**.

Why did Dr Strange mention traffic signal here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I recall the right point in the film, this is after Mordo had tricked Stephen by pretending to be his friend and imprisoned him and America Chavez prior to introducing him to the whole Illuminati.

At this point in the film Stephen is distrustful of Mordo and does not want to give him valuable information about our earth.

Telling him that you go on red is

- seemingly minor information
- inaccurate
- can potentially get you killed if you believe it

It is a snarky way to comply with the request while seeding disinformation.

Comment: Good point. Murderously snarky.

Comment: I don't think this explanation is correct.  The line in question comes before Mordo tricks Stephen Strange, not after.  He isn't saying it to Mordo; it's as if he's speaking under his breath to himself and America Chavez, conveying the idea "I can't believe I'm doing this [trusting Mordo]," or "Here goes nothing..."

Answer (score 6):

It's something of a trope when navigating the multiverse that arbitrary designations can get flipped.  Red means go or red means stop is definitely important to know for safety reasons.

While it was covered in the film too when Strange and Chavez are crossing the street...
See this Sliders (1995 TV series) commercial at 1:27 minute mark.

The Dr. Strange street crossing scene (in Hindi - you didn't jump universes)

Comment: Can't believe I forgot to mention the sliders example of the trope.

Comment: No. Dr Strange is lying, see the accepted answer.

Comment: No, this is quite correct. When Dr Strange states "You go on red" he is pointing out that the people in the universe he is now (you), go on red. Not  lying, but an explicit non-colloquial statement, almost an accusation if you observe the chiding tone he uses. THis should be the accepted answwer @MichaelBevans

Comment: @JiminyCricket. I need to rewatch the scene. From the transcript "you go on red" could be either a statement of how it works in 616 answering the question or a statement about how it works in 838 ignoring the question depending on tone as you've pointed out.

Comment: @JiminyCricket. I suspect you are correct, thank you for your take on the scene. Honestly, I like the ambiguity now that it has been raised, and if Strange was subtle enough there would be no way to tell :-) (I have't seen it since in the theater and I'm not seeing it on youtube.)  To Mr. Bevans - answers can complement one another.

Answer (score 0):

In this world, as previously established, you literally go on a red traffic signal, instead of a green one.

Figuratively, Mordo is a ["red flag"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_flag_(idiom)), being one of Strange's enemies in his own world.

Strange is choosing to go with Mordo despite this, reminding himself that things are different in other worlds (i.e. that this Mordo may be a friend rather than an enemy).

Comment: Chatgpt, is that you?

Comment: @Adamant no, it is not